# FastCGI Segmentation Fault on PHP 5.5.8

Tags: php, segmentation-fault, fastcgi

I'm using Debian 7 Wheezy with latest updates installed, including those from dotdeb-PHP repo. So PHP 5.5.8 is present.
I've installed eqDKP-plus (eqdkp-plus.eu) on my webserver. PHP is embedded through mod_fcgid in Apache.

Since 2 days everytime I visit any site of eqdkp I get response Code 500.
Following log-entries:

```
[Mon Jan 13 17:03:43 2014] [warn] [client xxxxxx] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server

[Mon Jan 13 17:03:43 2014] [error] [client xxxxxx] Premature end of script headers: viewnews.php

[Mon Jan 13 17:07:46 2014] [error] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper(16094) exit(communication error), get signal 11, possible coredump generated
```

Do you guys have any ideas on how solve this problem? In the last few days/weeks I didn't change anything on my server, so this makes no sense to me.